# Fixed-width Font .net Problem Between XP/Win7

Tags: .net, fonts

I built a .net application using Windows 7. One of the textboxes uses Consolas, a fixed-width font. When I run the application on XP some other non-fixed-width font is used. The fixed-width is important for legacy layout purposes.

What is going on here? Does XP somehow not have Consolas? Is there some other fixed-width font I can use?  Is this some other issue entirely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is indeed the case that `Consolas` was not originally part of XP.  I only got it when I installed it as part of VS 2005 or 2008 - I can't remember now - but I think MS offered it originally as a separate download or something like that.  It won't be redistributable, though - so clearly you won't be able to include it as part of your app.

I think it then became part of the OS offering from Vista onwards.

I would probably go with `Courier New` in the absence of Consolas; there's also `Courier` of course.  You could enumerate the installed Fonts first to see if Consolas is available and use an alternative if not - using the [InstalledFontCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.text.installedfontcollection.aspx.) class.

Answer (score 1):

I would assume that XP doesn't have Consolas, as it is a newer font than most system fonts.  Try an older font like Courier New, that has been packaged in Windows for a while.  See if that works for you.